# Information Regarding PhD Admissions

Tags: phd, mathematics

Are there universities that offer PhD in Mathematics without GRE or TOEFL in Europe?

I have completed my Masters in Applied Mathematics with a cgpa 8.0. I am keen to pursue research in Mathematics but I am not aware about the same. I would highly appreciate the comments in this regard.

Comment: You have to check with each institution ofering the PhD that you ate interested in - they have their own requirements / standards...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GRE is generally not used at all in Europe for Master/PhD admissions.

Another thing is TOEFL, if you will be studying in English you usually have to prove that you are proficient with the language, and there are multiple ways to do it. You have to check with particular institutions to what they require, it could be the TOEFL or IELTS or any other test of english, or proof that you have already completed a degree in English, etc.

Answer (score -2):

You need to write the GRE exam, is not a big deal and many funding opportunities in mathematics but you can research institutions in Germany ,Germany dnt need Gre

Comment: Welcome, Cryptobosslady! I know it's discouraging to get downvotes, especially if they don't say what's wrong. You have a partial answer here--that German institutions don't need GRE scores. But also the question was put on hold because it is a "shopping question," where it's especially hard to provide good answers that will still be helpful to other people, say who are searching a year later. Anyway, I hope you contribute on more questions, and many of us use the [edit] button extensively on our own answers, to improve them based on comments. :)